# Why getScript() is not working in my case

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load jQuery plugin based on the choice made as shown in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99FtJ/1/).
JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('img').each(function()
    {
        var th=$(this);
        var className=th.prop('class');
        var clas=['type1','type2','type3','type4','type5','type6','type7','type8','type9','type10'];
        var choice=((jQuery.inArray(className,clas))*1) + 1;
        var str="";
        var src=th.attr('src');
        var titleText=th.attr('alt');
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                    alert('fall under Type1')
                    str = '<a href="' + src + '" class="cloud-zoom" rel="adjustX: 10, adjustY:-4" target="_blank"/>';
                    th.wrap(''+str+'');
                    break;
            case 2:
                    str = '<a href="' + src + '" class="cloud-zoom"'; 
                    str+= 'rel="'+"position:'inside', showTitle: false, adjustX:-4, adjustY:-4"+'" target="_blank"/>';
                    th.wrap(''+str+'');
                    break;
        }
        if( choice == 1 || choice == 2)
        {
            $("head").append("<link>");
            css = $("head").children(":last");
            css.attr({
             rel:  "stylesheet",
             type: "text/css",
             href: "http://www.professorcloud.com/styles/cloud-zoom.css"
            });
       // In the js file method is invoking on domReady, That is why i am calling manually again on call back after wrapping HTML
            $.getScript("http://www.professorcloud.com/js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js", function(){
                $('.cloud-zoom').CloudZoom();
            });
        }
});
});
```

HTML

```
<img src="http://cdn.tripwiremagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/images/stories/Articles/best-jquery/serie3.jpg" class="type4" alt="jghdhefyhe" height="100px" width="130px">
```

In the fiddle method invocation is written under domReady. That might be causing the problem, because I am wrapping custom HTML to make that plugin work. Please have a look at the above fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that that problem is that you are trying to load a script from a server on a different domain. You should use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and set the option `crossDomain` to `true`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'your url',
  dataType: "script",
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function()
});
```

Comment: That is a completly different topic i think, maybe you should open a new question for that. You can look here though http://www.vidalquevedo.com/how-to-load-css-stylesheets-dynamically-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

An addition to your problem could be, that the var `src` is not set in your switch-cases. This is producing some additional errors.

Comment: Yeah, I found that when i was testing. But forgot to include the new code. Thanks for catching.